# list of all web applications installed on server?

Tags: monitoring, webserver

I have a home sever running a lot of different purposes, among other stuff it runs apache, mysql and torrent client. Some of these software is accessible through the web interface, but there is no consistent tool to see what is available. For example:

- phpmyadmin and munin are installed using OS package management tool (I use ubuntu), they are handled by apache and accessible via `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and `http://localhost/munin` correspondingly
- there is also third-party web application installed under `/var/www` and handled by apache
- transmission can run its own web server on a different port, i.e. `http://localhost:9091`
- from time to time I work on ruby-on-rails projects which again run services using build-in server

I wonder if there is an application which can track all the stuff accessible on the localhost through the web interface? It would be nice to use it for dynamic generation of `/var/www/index.html` file for simple assess to all application.